# Python sorting numbers on last digit?

Tags: python, sorting

My question is i have `inp=[1,52,234,65,87,57,96,0,3]` and output should be `output=[0,1,52,3,234,65,96,87,57]`. if the last digit is the same you leave them in same order as they are on input.increasing.

```
inp=[1,52,234,65,87,57,96,0,3]
output=[0,1,52,3,234,65,96,87,57]
```

how you sort integers on last digit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5):

You can [sort](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) using a [key function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) that calculates `n%10`:

```
sorted(inp, key=lambda n: n%10)
```

or

```
sorted(inp, key=(10).__rmod__)
```

Answer (score 1):

The last digit of a number is the remainder of division by 10:

```
sorted(inp, key=lambda x: x % 10)
#[0, 1, 52, 3, 234, 65, 96, 87, 57]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sorted()` built in with the keyword argument `key`:

```
sort = sorted(inp,
              key=lambda x: str(x)[-1])
```

This takes the value, converts it to a string to get the -1 index from it, then that value is able to be compared and sorted. *You don't need to cast it back into an integer.*